# Sort a vector based upon the unique value frequency

Tags: matlab, sorting, cluster-analysis

I'm clustering the rows of an `NxM` matrix using `kmeans`.

```
clustIdx = kmeans(data, N_CLUST, 'EmptyAction', 'drop');
```

I then re-arrange the rows of my matrix to such that adjacent rows are in the same cluster

```
dataClustered = data(clustIdx,:);
```

However every time I run the cluster analysis I get more or less the same clusters but with different identities. Thus the structure in `dataClustered` looks the same after each iteration but the groups are in different orders.

I'd like to re-arrange my cluster identities such that the the lower cluster identities represent dense clusters and the higher numbers are the sparse clusters.

Is there a easy and/or intuitive way to do this?

ie.  Convert

```
clustIdx = [1 2 3 2 3 2 4 4 4 4];
```

to

```
clustIdx = [4 2 3 2 3 2 1 1 1 1]
```

The identities themselves are arbitrary the information is contained in the grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to assign cluster label 1 to the cluster with most points, cluster label 2 to the cluster with the second most points, etc.

Assume you have a cluster label array called `idx`

```
>> idx = [1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]';
```

Now you can relabel idx like this:

```
%# count the number of occurrences
cts = hist(idx,1:max(idx));

%# sort the counts - now we know that 1 should be last
[~,sortIdx] = sort(cts,'descend')
sortIdx =
     2     3     1

%# create a mapping vector (thanks @angainor)
map(sortIdx) = 1:length(sortIdx);
map =
     3     1     2

%# and remap indices
map(idx)
ans =
     3     3     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
```

Comment: +1 Just have one suggestion. You could substitute the second `sort` by `map(sortIdx) = 1:numel(sortIdx);` - could be a bit faster. This is essentially an inverse permutation.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be efficient, but the easy way would be to first determine for each cluster how dense it is.

Then you can make a nx2 matrix that contains the `Density` and `ClusterIdx`

Afterwards a simple sort will give you the `ClusterIdx` in the right order